# Caliburn.Micro - resolving ViewModels from IoC container using Castle.Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro to build a composite UI app, and have decided to use Castle Windsor to build ViewModel objects, so that any services they need to operate can be injected automatically and avoid the servicelocator anti-pattern.

The problem is that Castle Windsor is using property injection to set the `ActiveItem` property of my viewmodel objects to (seemingly the first component it finds that matches the `IScreen` service) as it resolves them.

I don't want it to do this, because I want to set the active screen myself by calling `ActivateItem()` when I've worked out which viewmodel I want to render a view for.

It doesn't look like Castle Windsor can be made to **not** perform property injection (I'm using the fluent registration API with `IWindsorInstaller` classes), so what is a good approach to take here?

Should I *not* be resolving ViewModel objects from the container? If not, what's a good approach to avoid the servicelocator anti-pattern?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What **seems** to have worked for the time being, is the following:

```
_container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += model =>
{
    IEnumerable<PropertySet> nonInjectableProperties = model.Properties
        .Where(set => set.Property.Name == "ActiveItem").ToList();

    foreach (PropertySet nonInjectableProperty in nonInjectableProperties)
    {
        model.Properties.Remove(nonInjectableProperty);
    }
}
```

Essentially this is intercepting the resolution of the component and removing one of the properties from it, such that when the component is resolved, the kernel no longer sees an "ActiveItem" property to lookup a dependency for.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off property injection throughout the whole container, try the following:

`container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.RemoveContributor(container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.Contributors.OfType<PropertiesDependenciesModelInspector>().Single());`